# Closure not Working with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, closures

I'm using a looped ajax call with a closure but the value of the variable isn't being retained. It takes the value from the last iteration.

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    createElement(data[i], otherdata[i]);
}

function createElement(d,od){
    d.success = function(r) { console.log(od) };
    $.ajax(d);
}
```

lets say `otherdata= [1,2,3]`. the log will show '3' three times
any ideas why this is happening

Comment: `for(int i=0: i<data.length;i++){` should be `for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++){`

Comment: thanks. but this is just a simplification of my actual code for illustration purposes

Comment: I think you need to show a little more, how is the data-array created? What is otherdata?

Comment: Works perfectly fine if you fix the obvious syntax errors -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Whvc5/**

Comment: d.success and use of $.ajax(d) no sense...

Comment: @C-linkNepal - Sure it does, $.ajax accepts an object.

Comment: I mean inside ajax he is using just d and outside it d.success, so confusing to me.

Comment: @C-linkNepal - See the fiddle I posted above, maybe that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

There are no types in javascript, use `var` instead of `int` in your loop, and fix the syntax errors.

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    createElement(data[i],otherdata[i]);
}
```

Comment: @adeneo I suppose this would help too :)

Comment: @adeneo: Maybe I haven't had enough coffee this morning, but am I missing something? What other syntax errors are there?

Comment: @Matt There was `:` after `i=0` like `int i=0: i<data.length;i++`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below Use VAR instead of Int
Because Javascript don't know this, and also there is no colon (:) you have to use semi-colon instead(;)

```
 var data = [
    {},
    {},
    {}
];

var otherdata = [
    1,
    2,
    3
]

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    createElement(data[i], otherdata[i]);
}


function createElement(d, od) {

    d.success = function (r) {
    alert(od);

    };

    d.url = '/echo/json/';

    $.ajax(d);

}
```

Above code works perfect,
hope this helps...